# git submodule to npm dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, git-submodules

I working on Rails application of version 4.1.5. Rails application consists git submodules in it. I would like to change git submodules to npm package dependencies and include them to asset pipeline in a proper way. Could someone please suggest me gem or procedure to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a git submodule to an npm package remains a manual process.

You can see an example of such a procedure in [`xolvio/rtd` issue 61](https://github.com/xolvio/rtd/issues/61): Convert RTD to an NPM module instead of a git submodule.
It was resolved in [PR 163](https://github.com/xolvio/rtd/pull/163), and involved (that will differ depending on your own application):

- Updating paths in gruntfile for npm support
- [keeping `lib/bin` around](https://github.com/xolvio/rtd/pull/163/commits/3a14afcbcb640a684a22bdfb268c93c7520602cf)
- [Consolidate package deps and add `bin` to `package.json`](https://github.com/xolvio/rtd/pull/163/commits/75dd6f518f3a5285e922a6b8fc5b47a12d168226)